# Android Studio & Gradle: Multiple dex files

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, dependencies, libraries

Today I migrated to Android Studio 1.1 and started to update the version of some libraries. When I build the project using the gradle button everything seems work properly but when I try to run the application I read in the gradle console output the error message that you can see at the end of the post. For the error message is clear for me that some libraries are using internally some libraries that are common between my dependencies and they have likely different versions. Someone knows how can I discover what are the libraries in conflict and how can I fix that issue (I can not remove any library from the project). Below you can find an abstraction of the build files in my project. Thanks in advance :)

Project's gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

app's (main module) gradle file

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.myapp'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
    }
    release {
      debuggable false
    }
  }
  dexOptions {
     preDexLibraries = false
  }
  lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':facebook')
  compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
  compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.8.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'
  compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87' // Analytics, GCM
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
}
```

Gradle console output:

```
Error:Class android.support.v4.util.TimeUtils has already been added to output. Please remove duplicate copies.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/MyMAC/Documents/Development/IDE's/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/dx --dex --no-optimize .........
  Error Code:
    1
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/util/TimeUtils;
      at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
      at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:685)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    1 error; aborting
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove **android-support-v4** in **libs** folder in **facebook** proj or your app module